# What is a safe PCRE regex delimiter to use on HTML5 pattern input element attribute?

Tags: php, regex, html, pcre

It seems to be that the [HTML5 spec (and therefore ECMA262)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-pattern-attribute) allows `<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]/[0-9]" />` to match the string '0/0' even though the forward slash is not escaped. Web applications like Drupal would like to provide server-side validation for browsers that don't support HTML5 with something like:

```
<?php
preg_match('/^(' . $pattern . ')$/', $value);
?>
```

Unfortunately the string '[0-9]/[0-9]' is not a valid PRCE regex. It appears that most if not all HTML5-capable browser support both `pattern="[0-9]/[0-9]"` **and** `pattern="[0-9]\/[0-9]"` which begs the question - what can we use as a delimiter to run this pattern against Perl-style regex?

We've filed a [bug report against the W3C spec](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=15904) but are the browsers wrong here? Does the HTML5 spec need to be clarified? Is there a workaround we can use in PHP?

Comment: Good question, though as Alex pointed out, there is no solution.  As a sidenote, appending the `^` and `$` characters may already break the pattern, no?  Consider `$pattern = "(^|foo)bar"`.

Comment: The spec for the pattern attribute says to assume that it must match the entire string, not just part of it, so I think that would be an invalid pattern?

Answer (score 5):

I recomend using `"\xFF"` byte as pattern delimiter, because it is not allowed in UTF-8 string, so we can be sure it will not occur in the pattern. And because preg_match does not understand UTF-8, it will cause no trouble.

Example: `preg_match("\xFF$pattern\$\xFFADmsu", $subject);`

Please note `ADmsu` modifiers and adding `$`. The `u` modifier requires valid UTF-8 bytes only in the pattern, but not in delimiters around.

Comment: Latest Firefox and Chrome both allow a pattern of `\xFF` to match a literal 0xFF byte in a text input field.

Comment: opello: I just tried it and it did not work. I added `pattern="a\xFFb"` attribute to an input field and then entered this byte sequence (copied from hexeditor) and Chromium said that it does not match. Which I expect to be correct behavior since it is not valid UTF-8 string. However, I have not tried it on non-UTF-8 page.

Comment: I mocked up what I'd tested here:  http://jsfiddle.net/4nngJ/  and it still has the same result that I saw in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: My Firefox does not like even with selecting the text :) Here is [updated version](http://jsfiddle.net/JyNgA/2/) containing the value which should match. I see the input in red. You?

Comment: I see the same.  Upon closer inspection the value you have specified is actually 3 bytes, `0xEF 0xBF 0xBD` which actually corresponds to the Unicode Replacement Character code point and is not \xFF and should fail.  Please see [this further updated version](http://jsfiddle.net/JyNgA/3/) which has a `0xFF` byte in the value.  _Update:_ If you make the pattern in your earlier version \uFFFD it does validate.

Comment: Thanks. Getting wierd stuff thru my clipboard is harder than it looks.  Anyway, should we bother with escaping, filter these bytes out, or simply expect it won't happen? I guess there should be some unicode filtering done before values are processed at all, so "won't happen" is good for me.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure regarding the filtering or expectations you ask about.  I just commented because `\xFF` is a valid pattern, which seems to be opposed to the premise you were recommending this solution under.  I still haven't seen or thought of an example that breaks [my suggestion](#9530871).

Answer (score 4):

It is a valid regex if you use `#` instead of `/` for the delimiter. Example:

```
preg_match('#^('.$pattern.')$#', $value);
```

Comment: It seems that `#` is valid to use in $pattern as well. I could have `pattern="\#[0-9]"` or `pattern="#[0-9]"` and they would both match the string '#1' based on how browsers currently implement pattern matching.

Comment: Yes, it is a valid character to use, I just meant that you could use it as a work around as there is no *real* solution.

Answer (score 2):

One of the problems with PCRE is that almost *any* delimiter is legal for the start and end markers, depending on what makes the rest of the escaping easier.  So #foo# is legal, /foo/ is legal, !foo! is legal (I think), etc.  Undelimited regex, I'd say, are extremely dangerous for exactly that reason.  That sounds like an HTML5 spec bug that it doesn't specify.

Maybe in PHP, scan the string and pick a delimiter from a whitelist that is not present in the string?  (Eg, if there's no / use that, if there is use #, if that's there use %, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

I think `chr(0)` would work just fine. Edit: no. But `chr(1)` does work.

Comment: `chr(1)` is valid UTF-8 character, so it may occur in HTML form. Unlikely, but possible. I recomend using `"\xFF"` byte, because it is not allowed in UTF-8 string, so we can be sure it will not occur. And because preg_match does not understand UTF-8, it will cause no trouble. Example: `preg_match("\xFF$pattern\$\xFFADmsu", $subject);` (Please note `ADmsu` modifiers and adding `$`. The `u` modifier requires valid UTF-8 bytes only in the pattern, but not in delimiters around.)

Comment: You *absulutely* should post this as answer so we can upvote and Dave can accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Just enclose it in brackets or parentheses (yes, that's strange!):

```
<?php
preg_match('(^' . $pattern . '$)', $value);
?>
```

The manual states that you can use all corresponding pairs: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Not easy at first, but it clearly deals with ANY character you may use in between. For example `'(^(foo|bar)$)'` works as the final regular expression: `^(foo|bar)$`, without any potentially risky escapes.

Answer (score 0):

Given that a PHP application (Drupal in this case) is generating the input field, it seems like a workaround would be to do something along the lines of:

```
$pattern = '[0-9]/[0-9]';
...
$cleanPattern = preg_replace('/\//', '\\/', $pattern);
preg_match('/' . $cleanPattern . '/', $subject, $matches);
```

I couldn't think of a case where this wouldn't work, with `/` being used as a literal in the expression.

The HTML5 spec defers to ECMA262 for the legal pattern specification:

> If specified, the attribute's value must match the JavaScript Pattern production. [[ECMA262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf)]

Since there is BNF defined in ECMA262, a full parser (instead of using PCRE) seems like the safest approach.

Comment: What about `'\\/'`, which should match `'\/'`? Your code will convert it to `'\/'` matching `'/'`, but not matching expected `'\/'`.

Comment: I don't think that's the case, but it's frustrating to test within a shell.  An HTML5 pattern value of `\\/` to match `\/` entered without quotes in the input field can be matched by the PCRE `/^\\\/$/`.  As a test say `$pattern = '\\\\/';` (two escaped backslahes followed by an escaped slash).  The above `pcre_replace` makes `$cleanPattern` evaluate to `\\\/` which matches as desired as far as I can tell.

Comment: This should also probably be a `str_replace` instead of a `preg_replace` due to the simplicity of the match.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use T-Regx and let it choose the delimiter accordingly:

```php
<?php
pattern("^($pattern)$")->match($value);
```

it adds whatever delimiter was not used in the pattern.